# Get all nodes that do not have a specific relation

Tags: cypher

```
match (a:person {name:'John'} )-[r:KNOWS]->(b:person) return b
```

will give me all people known by John. How do I get all people NOT known by John?

Answer (score 0):

match (a:person {name:'John'} ), (b:person)
where not a-[:KNOWS]->b
return b